# Delete Certain Words from an Excel Cell based on a list

Tags: excel

I have a List of Words stored in one sheet of an excel. I want to delete these words if they appear in any cell of a particular column in another sheet. How can i  do that

Sample:

```
List(sheet B)
ALL WEATHER
LATEST


Data(sheet A)
Atext1 ALL WEATHER
Atext2
Atext LATEST
Atext ALL WEATHER
Atext 4
```

I want the output in Sheet A as:

```
Atext1
Atext2
Atext
Atext
Atext 4
```

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? [Edit] your question to show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is only one match per cell, you can use this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($E$1:$E$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$2,A1))),1)),""),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Youi This works beautifully. I did try to make sense out of this formula, but i could not still get a hang of it. Do you mind providing some explanation.

Comment: Aggregate returns the row number where the words are found in the string to the index which returns the value to the Substitute.

Comment: AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($E$1:$E$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$2,A1))),1). I have trouble in understanding how this returns the 1st smallest number and precisely how this works 
 ROW($E$1:$E$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$2,A1)))

Comment: 15 is small, 6 ignores errors, the division returns errors and row numbers in an array.  When the value is not found it return a #div0 error and the aggregate ignores it and only looks at the rows that return actual numbers.  Click on Evaluate Formula, it is under the formula tab, you will be able to see each step.